# Get lowest integer that is not in set

Tags: scala

Is there a better (functional or more idiomatic) way to get the first positive number that is not included in a set?

```
val set = Set(4, 1, 2, 0, 5)
var x = 0
while(set(x)) x += 1
println(x) // Should print 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try for a more functional expression that matches problem description more closely:

```
 Stream.from(1).filter(!set.contains(_)).head
```

[Caveat: I'm not a scala programmer, I have no idea how idiomatic this is]

Comment: I'am not a Scala programmer but it looks much more idiomatic than anything I could have done. Nice solution!

Answer (score 4):

`0` is considered positive? I think you should change the second line to:

```
var x = 1
```

If you want to get idiomatc, you can use tail recursion:

```
@tailrec def minNumNotInSet(s: Set, acc: Int):Int =
  if (s(acc)) minNumNotInSet(s, acc + 1) else acc

println(minNumNotInSet(Set(4, 1, 2, 0, 5), 1)
# 3
```

This goes with scala being a *functional* language. This version of the function is *immutable* - no elements change their value within it (no `x += 1`). This is more relevant to algorithms you might want to scale on a multi-processor multi-machine environment since it adhers to the [`Actor` model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model).

Comment: This being Scala, you would of course use `lowerCamelCase` instead of underscores ([sauce](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#constants_values_variable_and_methods)). And use the `@tailrec` annotation.

Comment: @amon - of course, you are right, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, for the additional answer! `0` is not positive indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution could hardly be more simple which is good.

Also, it will loop at most `n` times (worst case when integers from the set start at 0 and are consecutive). Each loop should take a constant time on average (property of a set). Worst case complexity is `O(n)` (actually in a really worst case, testing if a value is in a set takes a linear time but let's ignore this for the time being) which cannot be beaten because in the worst case, one will always need to inspect all n elements.

If you are a bit paranoid and don't want to rely on the unpredictable performance of set, you can look for other solutions but I'm not sure it's worth the pain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Performance is not an issue. I am simply new to Scala so I was curious if there is a neat functional way to do this.